# How can I alter methods in ContentTranslationHandler?

Tags: 8

I want to alter some of the methods here:
https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.8.x/core/modules/content_translation/src/ContentTranslationHandler.php

How can I alter just some of the methods?

Or can I override this class in any way?

Comment: There are mainly two ways 1- create a patch https://www.drupal.org/node/707484 then maybe you can apply it using composer patches. 2- override the method in your module by extending the class ContentTranslationHandler

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I've thought about overriding, but it is difficult as there are different core modules extending ContentTranslationHandler with their own subclasses. I'm not used to composer patches but will look into that, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome 

Comment: You can check this https://groups.drupal.org/node/518975